# how to configure the failover server for wmq in yml file

Tags: java, spring

```
 jms:
  connectionFactory:
    EMP_PAY:
      <<: *distributed_wmq_defaults
      hostName: EMP13.abc.COM,EMP14.abc.COM
      qManager: EMP13
      channel: EMP.CLIENT1
```

Above is the yml content where i have given both main server and failover server as comma separated values

Comment: Can you provide some code that results in the error?

Comment: The fail over scenario is not working here. Am i giving the correct syntax here? how to define the fail over server config in .yml file?